problema al convertir un archivo multipart
Estoy teniendo un problema con mi aplicación Spring al intentar manejar archivos multipart. Recibo el siguiente mensaje de error:
Failed to convert property value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile to required type byte[] for property imagen; Cannot convert value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile to required type byte for property imagen[0]: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile

Mi objetivo es vincular el archivo de imagen subido (MultipartFile) al campo byte[] imagen en mi entidad User. Aquí está cómo está estructurado mi código relevante:
Controlador (IndexController):
Tengo métodos para manejar la adición (/agregar) y actualización (/actualizar) de usuarios.
En ambos métodos, recibo el parámetro MultipartFile imagen para capturar la imagen subida desde el formulario.
Servicio (UserService):
En el método saveUser(User user, MultipartFile imagen), intento convertir el contenido de imagen a un arreglo de bytes (byte[]) usando imagen.getBytes().
Este método guarda la entidad User en la base de datos, incluyendo la imagen como un arreglo de bytes.
Formulario HTML (agregar.html):
Mi formulario incluye un campo de tipo file para que el usuario seleccione una imagen.
La acción del formulario apunta al controlador para procesar los datos de entrada y subir la imagen adjunta.
Configuración de Spring (application.properties):
He configurado las propiedades de carga de archivos multipart en mi archivo application.properties para permitir el manejo de archivos grandes y evitar errores de tamaño.
Sin embargo, al intentar ejecutar la operación de carga o actualización de usuario con una imagen adjunta, obtengo el error mencionado anteriormente. Parece que Spring está teniendo dificultades para convertir automáticamente el objeto MultipartFile al tipo requerido byte[] en mi entidad User.
les proporciono mi controlador:
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("mensaje", "Hola Mundo");
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String listUsers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("usuarios", userService.findAll());
        return "users";
    }

    @GetMapping("/agregar")
    public String addUserForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("usuario", new User());
        return "agregar";
    }

    @PostMapping("/agregar")
    public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("usuario") User usuario,
                          BindingResult result,
                          @RequestParam("imagen") MultipartFile imagen,
                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                          Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "agregar";
        }

        if (userService.findByNombre(usuario.getNombre()) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "El nombre de usuario ya está registrado");
            return "agregar";
        }

        if (userService.findByCorreo(usuario.getCorreo()) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "El correo ya se encuentra registrado");
            return "agregar";
        }
        try {
            userService.saveUser(usuario, imagen);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "El usuario ha sido agregado correctamente");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Error al procesar la imagen");
            return "agregar";
        }


        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @GetMapping("/editar")
    public String editUserForm(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        User usuario = userService.getUserById(id).orElse(null);
        if (usuario != null) {
            model.addAttribute("usuario", usuario);
            return "editar";
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Usuario no encontrado");
            return "redirect:/users";
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/actualizar")
    public String actualizar(@Valid @ModelAttribute("usuario") User usuario,
                             @RequestParam(value = "imagen", required = false) MultipartFile imagen,
                             BindingResult bindingResult,
                             RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "editar";
        }

        User usuarioActualizado = userService.getUserById(usuario.getId()).orElse(null);
        if (usuarioActualizado != null) {
            usuarioActualizado.setNombre(usuario.getNombre());
            usuarioActualizado.setEdad(usuario.getEdad());
            usuarioActualizado.setCorreo(usuario.getCorreo());

            // Manejar la carga de la imagen solo si se ha proporcionado una nueva
            if (imagen != null && !imagen.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    // Verificar tipo de contenido
                    String contentType = imagen.getContentType();
                    if (!"image/jpeg".equals(contentType) && !"image/png".equals(contentType)) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("El archivo debe ser una imagen JPG o PNG");
                    }

                    usuarioActualizado.setImagen(imagen.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            userService.saveUser(usuarioActualizado);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "Usuario actualizado correctamente");
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "No se encontró el usuario a actualizar");
        }

        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @PostMapping("/eliminar")
    public String deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        User user = userService.getUserById(id).orElse(null);
        if (user != null) {
            userService.deleteUser(user);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "El usuario ha sido eliminado correctamente");
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "El usuario no ha sido encontrado");
        }
        return "redirect:/users";
    }
}

mi clase de servicio:
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public Optional<User> getUserById(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public User saveUser(User user, MultipartFile imagen) throws IOException {
        if (imagen == null || imagen.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("La imagen es obligatoria");
        }

        // Normalize file name
        String fileImage = StringUtils.cleanPath(imagen.getOriginalFilename());

        try {
            // Check if the file's name contains invalid characters
            if (fileImage.contains("..")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence " + fileImage);
            }

            user.setImagen(imagen.getBytes());
            return userRepository.save(user);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException("Could not store file " + fileImage + ". Please try again!", ex);
        }
    }

    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }

    public User findByNombre(String nombre) {
        return userRepository.findByNombre(nombre);
    }

    public User findByCorreo(String correo) {
        return userRepository.findByCorreo(correo);
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}

mi html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Agregar Usuario</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-content">
        <h1>Agregar Usuario</h1>

        <div th:if="${errorMessage}" class="error-message" th:text="${errorMessage}"></div>
        <div th:if="${successMessage}" class="success-message" th:text="${successMessage}"></div>

        <form th:action="@{/agregar}" th:object="${usuario}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" th:field="*{nombre}">
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nombre')}" th:errors="*{nombre}" class="field-error"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="edad">Edad:</label>
                <input type="number" id="edad" th:field="*{edad}">
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('edad')}" th:errors="*{edad}" class="field-error"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
                <input type="email" id="correo" th:field="*{correo}">
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('correo')}" th:errors="*{correo}" class="field-error"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="imagen">Imagen:</label>
                <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen">
                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('imagen')}" th:errors="*{imagen}" class="field-error"></div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

y mis propiedades:
spring.application.name=users-app

# H2 Database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console


spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=200KB

¿Podrías ayudarme a entender qué podría estar causando este problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo? Estoy usando Spring para manejar la carga de archivos y estoy tratando de vincular un archivo subido a un arreglo de bytes en mi aplicación. Cualquier sugerencia sería muy apreciada.
¡Gracias!

Quizás las respuestas a esta pregunta (en inglés) te puedan servir para resolver tu problema.

muchas gracias!
